# Can't change the tint of segmented control

Tags: objective-c, colors, uisegmentedcontrol, tint

I have some problem with segmented control. I can't change the tint color, what ever color I set for the tint, segmented control is always gray as you can see on the picture.
Below is the code I'm using, changing the color of the button works.

```
UIColor *newTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(30.0f/255.0f) green:(98.0f/255.0f) blue:(134.0f/255.0f) alpha:1.0f];

[btnLogin setBackgroundColor:newTintColor];
[btnLogin setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[rememberMe setTintColor:newTintColor];
```

I forgot one thing, on application start segmented control has newTintColor, after login in application is displayed new view (split view), when user clicks on settings button, view for settings is displayed. Settings view has one segmented control for which I also can't change tint color (it is always gray) and logout button, if user clicks on logout button login view is displayed again and segmented control has gray tint instead of newTintColor.

[image]

Comment: This code seems to work fine. Are you sure `rememberMe` points indeed to the segmented control?

Comment: Yes, I connected segmented control from storyboard to .h file.
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *rememberMe;

Comment: I also tried to change the tint color through storyboard, but it is always gray.

Comment: "gray" suggests that someone passed through and set this view's tint adjustment mode to UIViewTintAdjustmentModeDimmed and then never set it back to Automatic.

Comment: @matt thanks, I just added self.view.tintAdjustmentMode = UIViewTintAdjustmentModeNormal; and now segmented control has the correct tint.

Comment: That's great! I'll add my suggestion as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gray color is a clue: it suggests that this view's tint adjustment mode has at some point been set to `UIViewTintAdjustmentModeDimmed` and then has never been set back to `Automatic`. See the docs on `UIViewTintAdjustmentMode`:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIViewTintAdjustmentMode